# Detecting water level in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, edge-detection

I have designed a surface with a shape like a rounded rectangle and I want to detect its exact boundaries in a photo I take from it. A sample photo is like this:

[image: Sample image]

I have tried thresholding the image but even after a Gaussian smoothing, the threshold won't give me an exact boundary.

Does anyone know of a technique that would give me the precise boundaries, regardless of the issues in lighting, etc?

**UPDATE:**
I'm sorry I didn't state the problem well, and actually I wasn't aware of the real problem (though I think it hasn't changed too much):

Here is the new photo. The photo is taken looking down inside a plastic bucket with a small amount of water inside, and I need to segment the region inside the water from the walls of the bucket, so I can detect the objects inside the water later. There is some lighting illuminating the bottom of the bucket from underneath (actually a sheet of plexiglass is placed instead of the original bottom).

[image: new image]

The problem is that the reflections of light on the wall make it the same color as where the water is, in some areas like the bottom-center in the sample image which makes it hard to find the water level.

Also, I would appreciate any hints on how should I differentiate between the boundary related to the plexiglass, and the boundary related to the water level.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold the power of shortest path.

The solution roughly follows what I did here: [Detecting and isolating part of an image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16786/detecting-and-isolating-part-of-an-image/16809#16809).

In this case we first treat the image by limiting every pixel value above the water-level grey to that same intensity.

[image]

Then performing shortest path on the inverse edge image created with a difference of Gaussian filter we get:

[image]

Resulting in the following segmentation:

[image]

My MATLAB functions that are needed for this solution:

http://imageprocessing.com.au/research/code/polarTransform.m http://imageprocessing.com.au/research/code/circularShortestPath.m http://imageprocessing.com.au/research/code/linearShortestPath.m

Code:

```
clear all
close all

%% Load image
I = imread('CabQx.jpg');
I = double(rgb2gray(I));
figure
imagesc(I);
colormap gray(256); 
title('Image');

%% Adjust intensity
Ia = I;
Ia(Ia > 49) = 49;
figure
imagesc(Ia);
colormap gray(256); 
title('Adjusted Image');

%% Bandpass Kernel
H1 = fspecial('gaussian',[100,100],8); % *** Changed filter size
H2 = fspecial('gaussian',[100,100],2);  % *** 
H = H2-H1;
H = mat2gray(H);
figure;
imagesc(H);
colorbar;
colormap gray(256); 
title('Bandpass kernel');

%% Edge Kernel
Hedge = imag(hilbert(H));
figure;
imagesc(Hedge);
colormap gray(256); 
title('Edge Kernel');

%% Edge filtered image
G = sqrt(imfilter(Ia,Hedge,'replicate').^2 + imfilter(Ia,Hedge.','replicate').^2);
G = max(G(:)) - G;
imagesc(G);
colormap gray(256); 
title('Inverse edge filtered image');

%% Shortest path
% Mid point
[r,c] = size(G);
r = floor(r/2);
c = floor(c/2);
% Min radius and max radius
min_radius = 100;
max_radius = 1000;
% Shortest path
[ path, energy, lastIndex, pathImage ] = ...
    circularShortestPath(G, 100, [c,r], [min_radius,max_radius], [400,720*2]);
figure;
imagesc(I);
hold on;
plot(path(:,1),path(:,2),'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
colormap gray(256); 
title('Shortest path');

%% Segment
figure
imagesc(I);
hold on;
fill(path(:,1),path(:,2),'r');
hold off;
colormap gray(256); 
title('Mask')

%%
J = zeros(size(I));
mask = roipoly(J,path(:,1),path(:,2));
segmentedI = I .* mask;
figure;
imagesc(segmentedI);
colormap gray(256); 
title('Segmented image');
```

Comment: That was awesome! I think I'll have a hard time converting it to OpenCV. Is there a reference paper I can read in case I don't understand the code?

Comment: Have a look at http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/lovell/aprs/accv2002/accv2002_proceedings/Sun852.pdf

Comment: In the above code I doubled the image (1/2 image extra patch size in the paper).  I'm actually dusting off some old code that does this in Emgu.CV in the next week, so I'll share it soon.

Comment: Wow! That's very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

Use level sets, or active contours. They are good at handling such problems and typically robust to noise. They're also sub-pixel accurate in certain respect. The best part is that many open source projects exist:

1. [Active Contour Segmentation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19567-active-contour-segmentation)
2. [Sparse Field Active Contours](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2009/04/sfm-and-active-contours/)
3. [Combination of Piecewise-Geodesic Paths](http://liris.cnrs.fr/julien.mille/code.html)